# Issue with os.walk function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying the get from user a string and place it in the `os.walk` function.
This is my code:

```
def FiletypeNumber():
    Path=Boaz.get()
    Pathw="'"+Path+"'"
    print (Pathw)
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(Pathw):
        f.extend(filenames)
    for i in range(len(f)):
        t = f[i]
        indexO=t.rindex('.')
        LenF=len(t)
        Ex=(t[-(LenF-indexO):])
        FileTypeList.append(Ex)
        if Ex in Typofiles:
            pass
        else:
            Typofiles.append(Ex)
```

When I print the variable `Pathw`, I get the wanted results (for example: `'d:\js'`).

But when I pass this variable to the `walk` function, my code doesn't work properly.
Its purpose is to:

1. Enter a directory.
2. Print the number and type of files in it.

Comment: `doesn't work properly.` what was the log, what did it do that you didnt think it would do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no reason to add ' to your pathstring. Why are you doing so?

Comment: probably for the `print` that follows. OP, if you want to `print` something quoted, instead of actually quoting it and thus changing it, you can do `print('{!r}'.format(Pathw))`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add `'` to your path name, such a path does not exist and results in a empty list.

```
def FiletypeNumber():
    path = Boaz.get()
    print('{!r}'.format(path))
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            FileTypeList.append(ext)
            if ext not in Typofiles:
                Typofiles.append(ext)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have changed this part :
    Path=Boaz.get()
    Path=('{!r}'.format(Path))
Still getting empty list